# How to disable area of Gridview before pressed a Button?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to make a simple game that select a value from item of Gridview. But i want that value just can clickable after press Play Button.We can't click in anywhere if did not press Play Button.  How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to change the clickable property of your grid view 
and then in the button click listener just set the clickable property to true 
so your code should look like the following:

let's assume that this is your view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false" />


</LinearLayout>
```

your activity should contain the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private GridView mGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // if you want to do it with setEnable

        mGridView.setEnabled(false);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mGridView.setClickable(true);

                // if you want to toggle then you can use the following code:
//                mGridView.setClickable(!mGridView.isClickable());

                // you can also change the setEnable property and not the clickable
                mGridView.setEnabled(true);


            }
        });

    }
}
```